# How to make a turtle pursue other turtle?

Tags: teleop, turtlesim

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys, I'm new on this issue (ROS system, I mean), and I know my question is so simple, but i'm having so much problems with it.
I don't know how to make a turtle which pursue other turtle, this one teleoperated by turtle_teleop_key node.
If someone can tell me how to do it, or just a clue, I'd be so grateful.
Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/85991/how-to-make-a-turtle-pursue-other-turtle?/) by [Irene.M](https://answers.ros.org/users/7306/irene.m/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-10-01

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) on 2013-10-01**:
Do you want the pursuing turtle to do so without receiving any teleoperation commands? If so, I say you would need a way to obtain the other turtle's position (for instance, through direct reporting) and implement a pose controller. I don't know any in ROS, but you can find the theory in books.

**Comment by [Irene.M](https://answers.ros.org/users/7306/irene.m/) on 2013-10-01**:
One turtle is teleoperated with turtlesim_teleop_key, and the other one has to pursue the first one. After reading all the tutorials from the ROS tutorials website, I don't know how I can give the position of the teleoperated turtle to the other turtle yet. Using topics is an option?

**Comment by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) on 2013-10-02**:
Yes! Each turtle has a /pose topic, which reports a turtlesim/Pose message

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-01-23**:
This sounds quite a bit like a homework assignment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a tutorial which does this. http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Introduction%20to%20tf

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0